# How to use 'the' in a sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context, grammar-myths

I am trying to define irony. Can you explain if the use of 'the' in the following sentence is grammatically correct?

"Involving the deployment of different levels of knowledge about an event, a situation  or a statement"

I think it's a general definition of irony hence 'the' before deployment shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "the" is correct and idiomatic.  You should compare your sentence to other dictionary definitions of irony.  It is common to use "the" or "a" in these definitions:

> the expression of one's meaning by using language that normally signifies the opposite

> a literary technique in which the full significance of a character's actions is clear to the audience but unknown to the character.

You could omit "the" to produce a kind of "telegraphese" but your sentence is better with it included.